How can I add the total values in pivot_table using margins?
df2 = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel(r"titanic.xls"))
result = df2.pivot_table(index=['pclass', 'survived'], aggfunc='size')
print(result)

Result



pclass
survived





1
0
123



1
200


2
0
158



1
119


3
0
528



1
181



the above code is simple. It's just that I wanted to get the total on every "pclass" "survived" and in my research I need to use margins=True in pivot_table()
df2.pivot_table(index=['pclass', 'survived'], aggfunc='size', margins=True)

Like this but when I run it, I encountered an error:
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'

I tried to make the excel into dataframe in a different line but its still the same.

this question is currently very messy. you should edit like this, how to ask a good question:
how to ask.
